# Firestore read and update is taking 1-12 sec delay to complete in Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase python client to write data to firestore.Any read / write operation at least takes 1 second to complete.Firestore DB is in us-central and our server is in Singapore.
Is it what causing issues?
During read, I have used a `where` query with `limit` like below.

```
collection_ref.where(
            u"field", u"==", u"field_value").limit(1).get()
```

During write, I use `set` and `update(dict)`

Sometimes the lag is around 10 to 12 sec

Did anyone face similar issues?

Any pointers will be appreciated

Comment: Based on this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-query-slow-e081fb8e55dd) I have given a list of reasons below.please check

Answer (score 0):

This article on [why is Cloud Firestore query slow](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-query-slow-e081fb8e55dd) mentioned the lists of reasons

> 1. If you are downloading a bunch of data you probably don’t need to download all of them.The solution would be to limit the amount that comes back.
> 2. Your offline cache is too big. Cloud Firestore does some amazing offline caching but this local cache does not apply the same indexes that the server does. This means when you query documents in your offline cache cloud Firestore needs to pack every documents stored locally  for the collection being queried and compare it against your query.The solution is limit how much data is being stored in offline cache.
> 3. Without composite indexing Firestore would have to do a lot of searching to get the results set.So instead, create a composite index so Firestore can do a quick lookup.
> 4. Used to Realtime Database.Realtime Database generally has a lower latency,you are not really going to notice the difference.But if app needs every second of latency you are probably better off using Realtime
>    Database in these scenarios.
> 5. The laws of physics are keeping you down. Your customer might be too far away from your Firestore Database and the actual latency is taking too long. To fix this use real time listeners which is a technique called latency compensation.